# calculate area for each layer in geojson in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have several polygons inside a geojson Now I want to calculate the area for each polygon
I used the following codes for this:

```
var feature = L.geoJSON(json).addTo(map)
feature.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    var area = L.GeometryUtil.geodesicArea(layer.getLatLngs());
    console.log(area))
})
```

But these codes return the value 0.
How can I calculate the area?

Comment: try using https://turfjs.org/docs/#area